# Android - Hide text cursor input React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am using React Native and I would like to remove the cursor from text input.

How can I remove the cursor either using JavaScript or Android Functionality ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try:

```
<TextInput caretHidden={true} ... />
```

See: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#carethidden

Answer (score 0):

Add caretHidden to the TextInput :

```
<TextInput caretHidden ... />
```